# is there a way to intercept an Axios request and return a custom response instead?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, axios

So I am trying to intercept my axios call in other return a custom response. I checked the `axios.interceptors` but it seems they are not used the way I want to use it.

```
const axios = require('axios')

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';
const request = axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url,
    });

// some middleware to intercept the request and return a custom response

request.then(customResponse => console.log(customResponse))
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? how do you decide to return `customResponse`?

Comment: Easiest way is to write your own wrapper around `axios` and modify your response there

Comment: the thing is..I don't want the request to actually be made let alone wait for the response to come back for me to modify. I hoping there was a way to do it with some axios method

Comment: If you don't want the request to happen you probably want to mock it? If interceptors not what you want you could try https://github.com/axios/moxios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter).

Example (from the documentation)

```js
var axios = require("axios");
var MockAdapter = require("axios-mock-adapter");

// This sets the mock adapter on the default instance
var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

// Mock any GET request to /users
// arguments for reply are (status, data, headers)
mock.onGet("/users").reply(200, {
  users: [{ id: 1, name: "John Smith" }],
});

axios.get("/users").then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```